# How to create a std::function alike wrapper?

Tags: c++

Attempted this:

```
template <class R, class... Ts>
class MyFunction
{
public:
    using func_type = R(*)(Ts...);

    MyFunction(func_type f)
      : m_func(f) 
    {
    }

    R operator()(Ts ... args) 
    {
        return m_func(args...);
    }

private:
    func_type m_func;
};

int Testfn(int a)
{
    std::cout << "value is " << a;
    return 42;
}

void Testing()
{
    MyFunction<int(int)> func(Testfn);
    std::cout << "Ret is " << func(1) << std::endl;
}
```

But fails with:

```
 error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1
 C2091: function returns function   
 C2091: function returns
 C2664: 'MyFunction<int (int),>::MyFunction(const MyFunction<int
 (int),> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)' to
 'int (__cdecl *(__cdecl
 *)(void))'
```

Compiler is MSVC2013.

Comment: `MyFunction<int(int)>` looks like it has one template parameter - a std::function. What does `MyFunction<int,int>` do?

Comment: That compiles but I wanted the int(int) style syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyFunction;

template<typename R, class... Ts>
class MyFunction<R(Ts...)>
{
public:
    using func_type = R(*)(Ts...);

    MyFunction(func_type f)
      : m_func(f) 
    {
    }

    R operator()(Ts ... args) 
    {
        return m_func(args...);
    }

private:
    func_type m_func;
};
```

`MyFunction` should be specialized for function signature type.
Note: `std::function` is really more complicated.

Comment: Strange, its forward declared with 1 arg, but then takes 1 and var args and sends the signature into itself? This is pretty confusing :)

Comment: @paulm specialization also takes one parameter, that is function signature